# Select those record only from table 1 where city exist against state id in table 2 in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

These are two sample table.
TABLE 1 state table

**id**  **state**

1   Delhi

2   Gujrat

3   jammu

4   punjab

5   maharastra

6   bihar

**id** **state_id** **city**

1   1       Delhi

2   2       Anand

3   3       jammu

4   4       Firojpur

5   6       Gaya

6   6       Patana

Select those record only from table 1 where city exist against state id in table 2 in PHP

Comment: Welcome TO Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
SELECT t1.* FROM
table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON(t2.state_id = t1.state AND t2.city!='')
```